# The REST API get the specific documents

Tags: rest, google-cloud-firestore, postman

A database of firebase:
[image]
How to get database to get the specific collection which **brand = SamSung** in this case using Postman. I am trying to figure out.

My URL get request:

[image]

In this case I use the conditional statements to get the products documents if the documents products have the **brand = SamSung**

My database:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I see, it has allDescendants property. When you set it to True, it will search and find all subcollection of the parent's collection and find out the information which desire my demand for select specific collection.